# When i try to install pyinstaller, I can't run the command

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I try to install and run it but I do this and it doesn't work.

```
C:\Users\Dino Non Admin>py -m pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\dino non admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\users\dino non admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller)
Requirement already satisfied: macholib>=1.8 in c:\users\dino non admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\dino non admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller)
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\dino non admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph>=0.13 in c:\users\dino non admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from macholib>=1.8->pyinstaller)
Installing collected packages: pyinstaller
  Running setup.py install for pyinstaller ... done
Successfully installed pyinstaller-3.3

C:\Users\Dino Non Admin>pyinstaller
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Also, for these files:

```
pyinstaller.exe
pyinstaller-script.py
```

When I open them it does this:

```
Pyinstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies.
Please install PyWin32 or PyWin32-ctypes
```

and I try to do what it says, but

```
C:\Users\Dino Non Admin>py -m pip install pypiwin32
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\dino non admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages
```

Comment: is python added in your local path ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install pywin32-ctypes`.

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller is an application not a package. You can use it without installing it in your PC. Just download it and extract it.

```
cd pyinstaller
```

The package you want to is `newscript.py`. I saved it in the pyinstaller folder. Now in order to create the executable file out of this script just run

```
`python pyinstaller.py newscript.py`
```

it will process the script and a folder called newscript will be created. The build folder is used by Pyinstaller for as a temporary container to contain the required packages and files. The dist folder will have the executable file.